# HTML5 Geolocation running slow on Android Oreo

Tags: html, geolocation, android-8.0-oreo, navigator

I have implemented the HTML5 geolocation function to get the user's current position. We have tested it in every browser and on Android 7x phones.

However, on Android 8 the location of the user runs very slow and takes up several seconds. It doesn't matter which way of location (GPS, network) is used.

Here's the coding for the location:

```
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    this.saveLocationData.bind(this), 
    this.getLocationError.bind(this),
    {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 5000
    }
    );
```

It always timeouts and takes up to 8! seconds. On Android 7 it took not more than 2 seconds.

Comment: Are you able to fix this @thomas ?